# What is the axis system followed in rviz?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is very basic question , sorry for asking but i can't find the information ..
What is the Grid plane in rviz , is it XY or YZ or ZX ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10622/what-is-the-axis-system-followed-in-rviz-??/) by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 175 on 2011-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default plane is `XY`, but you can change this. There is extensive documentation on the `rviz` wiki page, specifically http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Grid in the Plane section.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rajat](https://answers.ros.org/users/591/rajat/) on 2011-07-17**:
Ohk Great!! Thanks .